# how to convert yyyymm number string into end month date using vba?

Tags: vba, excel

Currently, in my Excel, there is a string of year and month written as yyyymm.
Eg: 201706

Right now I would like to convert it into the end of month date in another worksheet. Eg: 20170630

The question now is, how do I tell Excel to auto create the day based on the month value in the string?

I was planning on using if statements to declare each month based on the ending value at the back of the string. (ie: If 2017**06** , date = 20170630)

But then I thought that won't work for February's leap year. Is there another method to use besides that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
dtmDate = 201706 (or put there value from cell)

dhLastDayInMonth = DateSerial(Left(dtmDate, 4), Right(dtmDate, 2) + 1, 0)
```

Comment: it works thanks. although out of curiosity, what does the "+ 1, 0" portion of the code does?

Comment: The `Right(dtmDate, 2)` returns the month and `+1` adds one to it so will refer to July.  The 0 is the day number - day number 0 is effectively the last day of the previous month, so 30th June.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to solve your problem is to not even use a vba makro. Using the `Date`, `Left`and `Right` as well as `EOMonth` functions you can sinply convert your string to a date like in the example below.

Using this you don't even need vba:

`=EOMONTH(DATE(LEFT(A1;4);RIGHT(A1;2);1);0)`
(example if date string is in A1)

Check out [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-last-day-of-month) page to get more detail on  this function

Comment: Example usage: `=EOMONTH(LEFT("201711",4)&"-"&RIGHT("201711",2)&"-01",0)`

Answer (score 1):

I often use a little workaround by taking the first day of the following month (which is always the 1st) and subtract 1 of the date. Unfortunately that only works with Date-Values:

Try this one:

```
Sub LastDayOfMonth()

    strInput = "201711"
    y = Left(strInput, 4)
    m = Right(strInput, 2)

    dat = DateSerial(y, m + 1, 1) - 1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim dLast As Date
 dLast = DateAdd("d", -1, CDate("1/" & Format(Date, "mm/yyyy")))
```

Or through a messageBox if you put the date in cell A1:

```
MsgBox Format([eomonth(A1,6)], "dd/mm/yyyy")
```