# Excel Macro issue: 1) Type mismatch on date 2) Setting complex condition

Tags: vba, excel

Sorry for the confusing title. But I can't think of a better way of describing my problem.

I have a sheet of data in Excel that merges data from 2 separate sheets, places them in an allocation sheet and finally put them in another worksheet for display. Currently the display is like so:

```
+----+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+--------+
| NO |   Date    | Header  | Line Item | GL Acc  | Amount |
+----+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+--------+
|  1 | 20171031  | Header1 |     1     | 1000001 | 9.50   |  
|  1 |           |         |     2     | 1000001 | -9.50  | 
                              .
                              .
                              . 
|  1 |           |         |    901    | 1000002 | 6.80   |
|  1 |           |         |    902    | 1000002 | -6.80  |
+----+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+--------+
```

Note that this is a simplified table. When this table is running there can be up to thousands of rows of data. Now I would like to make it so that the table will create a new Date and Header date and restart the Line Item to 1 again when it reaches 900 count. However there is also the condition that the GL Acc cannot have any balance when it is separating.

For Example:

```
+----+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+--------+
| NO |   Date    | Header  | Line Item | GL Acc  | Amount |
+----+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+--------+
| 1  | 20171031  | Header1 |    1      | 1000001 | 9.50   |
| 1  |           |         |    2      | 1000001 | -9.50  |
                              .
                              .
                              . 
|  2 |           |         |    1      | 1000002 | 6.80   |
|  2 |           |         |    2      | 1000002 | -6.80  |
+----+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+--------+
```

This is the original code snippet for the module:

```
Sub upload_Entry()
Dim NextID
Dim CID
Dim Header
Dim accdate, accdate1
Header = 1
NextID = 0
runv = 3
SQID = 0
LastRow = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ALLOCATION").Cells(7, 10) * 2

For C = 3 To ((LastRow + 2))

    SQID = SQID + 1
    If Header = 1 Then
        accdate = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ACCT_LINE").Cells(runv + 2, 2)
        accdate1 = DateSerial(Left(accdate, 4), Right(accdate, 2) + 1, 0)
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("UPLOAD_ENTRY").Cells(C, 2) = accdate1       ' DOC_DATE
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("UPLOAD_ENTRY").Cells(C, 3) = "Header1"
        Header = 0
    End If

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("UPLOAD_ENTRY").Cells(C, 4) = SQID 'Line Item
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("UPLOAD_ENTRY").Cells(C, 5) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ALLOCATION").Cells(runv + 6, 8) 'GL ACC
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("UPLOAD_ENTRY").Cells(C, 6) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ALLOCATION").Cells(runv + 6, 13) * -1    'Amount
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("UPLOAD_ENTRY").Cells(C, 1) = 1  'NO

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("UPLOAD_ENTRY").Cells(C + 1, 1) = 1 ' NO
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("UPLOAD_ENTRY").Cells(C + 1, 4) = SQID + 1
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("UPLOAD_ENTRY").Cells(C + 1, 5) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ALLOCATION").Cells(runv + 6, 8) 'GL ACC
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("UPLOAD_ENTRY").Cells(C + 1, 6) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ALLOCATION").Cells(runv + 6, 13)
```

Sorry for the messy code. The original was much worse.

My 1st agenda was to make it so that the date and header can create in different rows since the code only shows it placing those values on the 1st row only.

Thus I came up with this code:

```
Sub upload_Entry()
    Dim NextID
    Dim CID
    Dim Header
    Dim accdate
    Header = 1
    NextID = 0
    runv = 3
    SQID = 0
    LastRow = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ALLOCATION").Cells(7, 10) * 2 'dictaces how many rows created     

     For C = 3 To ((LastRow + 2))

    CID = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ALLOCATION").Cells(runv + 6, 2) 'B9

    If NextID <> CID Then
    'If Header = 1 Then
        SQID = 0
        SQID = SQID + 1

        accdate = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ACCT_LINE").Cells(runv + 2, 2)  ' or Cells(5, 2)//B5
        accdate1 = DateSerial(Left(accdate, 4), Right(accdate, 2) + 1, 0) 
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("UPLOAD_ENTRY").Cells(C, 2) = accdate1
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("UPLOAD_ENTRY").Cells(C, 3) = "Header1"
    Else
        SQID = SQID + 1
    End If

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("UPLOAD_ENTRY").Cells(C, 4) = SQID
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("UPLOAD_ENTRY").Cells(C, 5) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ALLOCATION").Cells(runv + 6, 8) 'GL ACC
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("UPLOAD_ENTRY").Cells(C, 6) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ALLOCATION").Cells(runv + 6, 13) * -1 'Amount

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("UPLOAD_ENTRY").Cells(C, 1) = CID ' id
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("UPLOAD_ENTRY").Cells(C + 1, 1) = CID ' id
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("UPLOAD_ENTRY").Cells(C + 1, 4) = SQID + 1
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("UPLOAD_ENTRY").Cells(C + 1, 5) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ALLOCATION").Cells(runv + 6, 8) 'GL ACCT
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("UPLOAD_ENTRY").Cells(C + 1, 17) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ALLOCATION").Cells(runv + 6, 13)   'Amount

    NextID = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ALLOCATION").Cells(runv + 6, 2)
    C = C + 1
    runv = runv + 1
    SQID = SQID + 1

      Next C
End Sub
```

The good news is I managed to get the Header to duplicate. But the Date shows Type Mismatch on code:

```
accdate1 = DateSerial(Left(accdate, 4), Right(accdate, 2) + 1, 0)
```

***Edit Start***

The date comes from a sheet where its format is only year and month (201710), when using the original code, the accdate1 code help me get the default last day of the month and fills the complete date in the sheet (20171031).

***Edit End***

Thus that is one problem I have. Another major problem is I'm not sure how to set such a complex condition on separating line into new NO when rows reaches 900 and also keep track the balance at the same time.

Is there anyone out there that can help? The more I try and solve this the more cross-eyed I become. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When it errors hover over `Left(accdate, 4)` and `Right(accdate, 2)`. What values does it display?

Comment: I assume you are reading a cell that is empty for `accdate`. This will bring the `DateSerial` to fail. Btw: Is it on purpose that you set the day-part of the `DateSerial`  to `0`?

Comment: @FunThomas Yes. The date is captured from a sheet that has year and month format only '201710'. And the program will give me the last day of the month by default. I actually made that change long ago based on this question I asked. [link'(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45073672/how-to-convert-yyyymm-number-string-into-end-month-date-using-vba)

Comment: @Zerk When I get the error, I checked the value the sheet captured. Surprisingly, the correct date can display. for example if the reference sheet's value is 201710, the selected cell in my main sheet shows 20171031. Just that I keep getting the mismatch error every time.

Answer (score 0):

For the example with `Date=20171031`, `DateSerial(Left(accdate, 4), Right(accdate, 2) + 1, 0)` is gonna fail in giving the next day as a result. Maybe these changes ?

```
Dim D as Date
...
If IsDate(accdate) Then
    D = DateSerial(Left(accdate, 4), Mid(accdate, 5, 2), Right(accdate, 2))
    D = D + 1
Else
    D = DateSerial(1983, 1, 19) ' launch date of Apple Lisa
End If
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("UPLOAD_ENTRY").Cells(C, 2) = Format(D, "yyyymmdd")
```

Comment: I probably should have added in the question that the date format from source sheet is actually 201710 (year & month) only. When the date copies into this sheet, it will automatically generates the last day for the month becoming 20171031. Also 'DateSerial(Left(accdate, 4), Right(accdate, 2) + 1, 0) ' worked out just fine. Someone on this site recommended the code for me in the past, and he gave me a decent explanation on how it works. You can check it out here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45073672/how-to-convert-yyyymm-number-string-into-end-month-date-using-vba)

Comment: Nice solution! I will elaborate the fail.

Answer (score 0):

I added some error-trapping-code which displays some info about the troubling row in the immediate window. As example for creating this output, I entered `17/11` in cell `B11` in sheet `ACCT_LINE`, pretending I lost the preceding `20` for the year.

```
    ...
    accdate = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ACCT_LINE").Cells(runv + 2, 2)  ' or Cells(5, 2)//B5
    On Error Resume Next
    accdate1 = DateSerial(Left(accdate, 4), Right(accdate, 2) + 1, 0)
    If Err.Number > 0 Then
        Debug.Print "'Err " & Err.Number & " for accdate := " & accdate & _
            " // CID := " & CID & _
            " // runv := " & runv & _
            " // value2 := " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ACCT_LINE").Cells(runv + 2, 2).Value2
        Debug.Print "'Err " & Err.Description
        Stop
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
```

In the immediate-window, I receive :

```
Err 13 for accdate := 17/11/2017 // CID := 12 // runv := 9 // value2 := 43056
Err Type mismatch
```

Comment: well the on error resume next technically works. but I can imagine that's not gonna work for my boss. I'll use it for now, just to get this issue off my back temporarily. Thanks.